# Gitlab CI token - 403 with apache

Tags: apache, continuous-integration, apache2, gitlab

I'm running gitlab on my server. I'm serving the website with apache2 (with https).

Recently I got started with gitlab CI, but ran into a problem I just can't resolve on my own: I always get a 403 error:

```
remote: Access denied
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.mydomain.com/group/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Both SSH and HTTP(S) are enabled for cloning and ci works just fine with public projects, checking all gitlab logs reveals that the runner isn't authenticated  thus triggering a 403.

My best guess is that the apache configuration doesn't pass the ci-token to gitlab, but neither do I know how I can check that, nor do I believe that this is truly the cause.

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.mydomain.com
  ServerSignature Off

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCipherSuite     "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
  Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"
  SSLCompression Off
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/git.mydomain.com/chain.pem

  ServerName git.mydomain.com
  ServerSignature Off

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

  <Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.mydomain.com/
  </Location>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on

  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gitlab.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Relevant part of /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'https://git.mydomain.com'

nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'webmaster@mydomain.com'
```

The Runner config:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner Name"
  url = "https://git.mydomain.com/ci"
  token = "Some generated token"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

/etc/default/gitlab:

```
gitlab_workhorse_options="-listenUmask 0 -listenNetwork tcp -listenAddr 127.0.0.1:8181 -authBackend http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - compile

compilei7:
    stage: compile
    script:
        - /./home/public/folder/someScript.sh -f `$PWD`
    tags:
    - neededtag
```

All help is appreciated, I ran against a wall here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this was fixed for me in one of the updates released since I posted this question as it is now working, using the exact same server and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a GitLab Runner tries to clone the project from the Git repo.

In order to solve that problem, add yourself as a member of the project:

1. Go to your project in GitLab.
2. From the menu in the left sidebar, select the *Settings / Members* entry.
3. In the *Select member to invite* input field, type your name (or name of the member that pushed his code).
4. In *Choose a role permission*, select *Developer*.
5. Click the *Add to project* button.

Comment: Normally, yes. In this case gitlab was/is selfhosted with a shell-runner running on the same server. The runner was registered with the CI Token to be able to clone the source code. That should suffice for the runner to have access to the project. The problem here was that it didn't; but as I wrote below it magically worked after some time (between a few weeks and a year, didn't check between) without me changing anything at all.